# Sfml how to make a shape move to a certain point

Tags: c++, interpolation, sfml

I am having a trouble implementing an interpolation to move an object to a point in my screen.

Here is the code:

```cpp
factor += timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() * speed;

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  circleObjectArray[i].setPosition(Interpolate(movePositionsX[rand() % 5], movePositionsY[rand() % 5], factor));
  window.draw(circleObjectArray[i]);
}
```

And I want to use this body of the interpolate function but I'm not able to call it

```cpp
sf::Vector2f Interpolate(const sf::Vector2& pointA, const sf::Vector2& pointB, float factor) {
  if(factor > 1.f)
    factor = 1.f;
  else if(factor < 0.f)
    factor = 0.f;
  return pointA + (pointB - pointA) * factor;
}
```

Thank you for you time :D

Comment: what is your question? what trouble do you have? Is the code not doing what you want it to do? What do you want it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: _"I am having troubles"_ isn't a particularly clear and concise problem description. Post a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: I accidentally posted the wrong part of the code i have updated it now, how do i use the interpolate function with this body "
    sf::Vector2f Interpolate(
    const sf::Vector2& pointA,
    const sf::Vector2& pointB,
    float factor
) {
    if( factor > 1.f )
        factor = 1.f;

    else if( factor < 0.f )
        factor = 0.f;

    return pointA + (pointB - pointA) * factor;
}
"

Comment: still we cannot know why you are "not able to call it". Do you get a compiler error? Please post a [mcve] and the error message

Comment: it gives an error in the setposition command saying that the interpolate isnt declared and in the line sf:Vector2f Interpolate it says invalid use of template-name 'sf::Vector2' withouth an argument list, do i need to declare the vector2f interpolate outside my main function or should i create a class for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your shapes *time to move*. For each shape you should store the three inputs of your interpolate function. Then, update the factor a little bit every frame and render it by calling Interpolate with the stored arguments. For example, adding 1/60  every frame will make the shape do the complete move in one second at 60 fps.

When the factor reaches 1, select new parameters for the next transition like you do now, or maybe wait a few frames to select the next target. It's up to you.

As for your actual compile error: `sf::Vector2` is a template type. You cannot use it by itself. Either write `sf::Vector2<float>`, or use the predefined type alias `sf::Vector2f`.

Comment: Im sorry but can you please explain the last part better it still gives the same error even when i write sf::Vector2<float>

Comment: Did you `#include <Vector2.hpp>` in the file that defines `Interpolate`? Also make sure to define it as a global function, not inside another (that is a nonstandard extension and often just a syntax error.)

Comment: it now says that Vector2.hpp: no such files or directory

Comment: @AndréSousa it should be `#include <SFML/System/Vector2.hpp>` instead of `#include <Vector2.hpp>`